# can't push to gitlab, failed and rejected

Tags: gitlab, git-commit, git-push, git-pull, git-fetch

> has been pulled, the result is still an error `! [rejected]  dev->dev(non-fast-forward)`

```
D:\PPI_Roketin\Project\astrowatch (dev)
λ git add resources/views/reals/_form.blade.php

D:\PPI_Roketin\Project\astrowatch (dev)
λ git commit -m "resources/views/reals/_form.blade.php"
[dev db5ac99] resources/views/reals/_form.blade.php
1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

D:\PPI_Roketin\Project\astrowatch (dev)
λ git push origin dev
To gitlab.com:roketin-stellar/astrowatch.git
! [rejected]        dev -> dev (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:roketin- stellar/astrowatch.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

> error like this, why?

[image]

> have done git checkout, and repeated the command, it's still an error like above

Comment: first, commit your local changes or stash your changes. Then checkout branch and pull changes. After that u can merge changes and push

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic git error.  The problem is described in the error message: `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`, which means that there have been changes to the remote branch that you do not have locally. There are quite a few ways to fix this, one of which is also described in the git message: `Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`

If you do `git pull origin dev` this will merge whatever changes are made in the remote to your local branch.  Once you fix the merge conflicts, you can then push the branch.

Another option would be to run a rebase by performing `git pull --rebase origin dev`, which will bring in the remote changes and rebase your commits on top of the remote commits. This will result in a cleaner git history.

The easiest for now would probably just doing a `git pull`, then once it's merged correctly, pushing to your remote.

I definitely recommend researching the git commands and learning how to find the resources correctly in the docs.  There is a lot available online.

Answer (score 1):

you can try `git reset --hard HEAD`
please remind that:
**HEAD points to your current branch (or current commit), so all that git reset --hard HEAD will do is to throw away any uncommitted changes you have.**

Answer (score 0):

It's quite self explanatory, you need to keep yourself upto date with remote branch if you want to commit and it looks like git pull will overwrite files you've made changes to. You should commit your changes first.